# PHP Header not redirecting after submit

Tags: php

I have read several posts on how to do this and at one point my code was functioning properly but it no longer works.  When the user submits, it should

a) give them a warning modal if there were errors, or
b) use a header to re-direct them to a thankyou.php page.  It no longer does this.

after a form submit with no errors, it reloads the page to be blank and the url still says ourpeachwedding.com/#rsvp.  it should redirect to ourpeachweddding.com/pages/thankyou.php.`

```
<?php
    $modalMessage="<p class='lead'>Thank you for visiting our page, and please be sure to <a onclick=$('#myModal').modal('hide') href='#rsvp' >RSVP</a> if you haven't already. If you RSVP'd on our page previous to April 14th, 2017, please do so again, as our email was not recieving messages due to some coding errors. Thank you!</p>";

    $modalTitle="Welcome!";

    if ($_POST["submit"]) {

      if (!$_POST["name"]) {
        $error.="<br> Please enter the name on your invitation.";
        $nameError="<p class='inlineError'>Please enter the name on the invitation.</p>";
      }
      if (!$_POST["head-count"]) {
        $error.="<br> Please enter the size of your party.";
        $headCountError="<p class='inlineError'>Please enter the size of your party.</p>";
      }
      if (!$_POST["attending"]) {
        $error.="<br> Please let us know if you will be able to make it or not.";
        $attendingError="<p class='inlineError'>Please let us know if you will be able to make it or not.</p>";
      }
      if (!$_POST["reception-check"]) {
        $error.="<br> Please let us know if you will be attending the reception.";
        $receptionCheckError="<p class='inlineError'>Please let us know if you will be attending the reception.</p>";
      }
      if ($error) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>There were errors in your form.</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
        $modalMessage = $result;
        $modalTitle = "Sorry! Looks like there was a mistake, please fill in the entire form.";
} else {
        if (mail("dprb17@gmail.com", "RSVP", "

        Name: ".$_POST['name']."

        Head Count: ".$_POST['head-count']."

        Attending?: ".$_POST['attending']."

        Reception Check: ".$_POST['reception-check']."

        Comments: ".$_POST['comments'])) {
          header('Location: http://www.ourpeachwedding.com/pages/thankyou.php');
          exit();
        } else {
          $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Sorry, there was an error submitting your rsvp, please try again.</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
        }
      }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Check your logs and possibly enable error-reporting if its not enabled. You are likely to be finding "*Headers already sent..*" error, or another error explaining why it isn't redirecting.

Comment: @Qirel I did enable error reporting in php.ini and no errors show when i submit it.  You could test it yourself on the live site at ourpeachwedding.com.  If you could help me out i would appreciate it.  My code looks alright though?

Comment: At the top of your file, add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` directly after `<?php`. Either the `header()` call is never reached logically (it never has the right condition to do so), or there is some sort of output prior to the call.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas not sure how your form is set up.

Should this

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
```

be this

```
if ($_POST["submit"] == 'submit') {
```

and these blocks where you are checking if it is not true

```
if (!$_POST["name"]) {
        $error.="<br> Please enter the name on your invitation.";
        $nameError="<p class='inlineError'>Please enter the name on the 
        invitation.</p>";
      }
```

be like this where you are checking if they are empty

```
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $error.="<br> Please enter the name on your invitation.";
        $nameError="<p class='inlineError'>Please enter the name on the 
        invitation.</p>";
      }
```